# Create table from query result rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Within SQL Server 2005, I need to create a table dynamically based upon the *rows* returned from a query.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
```

returns the following rows

1. Forename
2. Surname
3. DOB

And I'd like a table created like so:

```
Forename, Surname, DOB.
```

I plan to use this procedure on a number of different sources therefore the returned rows will be different each time.

Many thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `SELECT INTO` in conjunction with `PIVOT`:

See:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx
- http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7126.asp
- http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx

I don't have access to SQL Server right now, but I would go for something like this (based on the links above):

```
SELECT [0] 
INTO TableB
FROM
    ( SELECT id, colName FROM TableA ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
    ( AVG(id) FOR colName IN [0] ) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: This isn't creating a table from the rows returned and would require me to manually create a SELECT INTO query.

Comment: I haven't read the question right, sorry. Hope now it helps (updated).

Comment: Thanks, pkk. I followed the instructions in the simple talk article and it worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

The following query creates a dynamic sql statement that can be executed. You may need to have a separate column in yourtable that has the column's datatype definition as well.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = coalesce(@sql + ', 
    ' + yourcolumn + ' varchar(255)',
    yourcolumn + ' varchar(255)')
from yourtable

select @sql = 'create table tableA(' + @sql + ')'

--exec sp_executesql @sql
select @sql
```